# Aggregation Project Group By extracted day, month and year with Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-mongo

To be direct, how do i do this:

```
group._id = { 
    year: { $year : [{ $subtract: [ "$timestamp", 25200000 ]}] }, 
    month: { $month : [{ $subtract: [ "$timestamp", 25200000 ]}] }, 
    day: { $dayOfMonth : [{ $subtract: [ "$timestamp", 25200000 ]}] }
};
```

with spring Data

I tried this already and some other forms and were not successfull

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(c),
                Aggregation.project("programa", "custo", "duracao", "dataHora")
                    .andExpression("dataHora").minus(25200000).extractDayOfMonth().as("dia")
                    .andExpression("dataHora").minus(25200000).extractMonth().as("mes")
                    .andExpression("dataHora").minus(25200000).extractYear().as("ano"),
                Aggregation.group("programa", "ano", "mes", "dia")
                    .count().as("count")
                    .sum("custo").as("valorTotal")
                    .sum("duracao").as("duracaoTotal")
                    .first("dataHora").as("dataHora"),
                Aggregation.sort(Direction.ASC, "dataHora")
        );
```

I need to group by day, month and year in mongodb, or else i will need to convert all this grouped data in code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into a limitation of spring mongo in what you can do for field calculations in a single [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage, and indeed you are likely already writing as a separate `$project` since you discover that you cannot project custom named fields directly in a [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) `_id` at present either.

So you would be better off keeping this all in the `$group`, as well as using a different method for rounding your adjusted dates to local time.

The better way to write your `$group` would therefore be:

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": {
    "programa": "$programa",
    "dataHora": {
      "$add": [
        { "$subtract": [
          { "$subtract": [{ "$subtract": ["$dataHora", new Date(0)] }, 25200000 ] },
          { "$mod": [
            { "$subtract": [{ "$subtract": ["$dataHora", new Date(0)] }, 25200000 ] },
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
          ]}
        ]},
        new Date(0)
      ]
    }
  },
  "count": { "$sum": 1 },
  "valorTotal": { "$sum": "$custo" },
  "duracaoTotal": { "$sum": "$duracao" },
  "dataHora": { "$first": "$dataHora" }
}}
```

Of course to use this sort of structure with spring-mongo you need a custom implementation of the aggregation stage operation that can take a defined `DBObject`:

```
public class CustomGroupOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;

    public CustomGroupOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

Which you then use in context like this:

```
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(c),
            new CustomGroupOperation(
                new BasicDBObject("$group",
                    new BasicDBObject("_id",
                        new BasicDBObject("programa","$programa")
                            .append("dataHora",
                                new BasicDBObject("$add",Arrays.asList(
                                    new BasicDBObject("$subtract",Arrays.asList(
                                        new BasicDBObject("$subtract",Arrays.asList(
                                            new BasicDBObject("$subtract",Arrays.asList(
                                                "$dataHora", new Date(0)
                                            )),
                                            25200000
                                        )),
                                        new BasicDBObject("$mod",Arrays.asList(
                                            new BasicDBObject("$subtract",Arrays.asList(
                                                new BasicDBObject("$subtract",Arrays.asList(
                                                    "$dataHora", new Date(0)
                                                )),
                                                25200000
                                            )),
                                            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                                        ))
                                    )),
                                    new Date(0)
                                ))
                            )
                    )
                    .append("count",new BasicDBObject("$sum",1))
                    .append("valorTotal",new BasicDBObject("$sum","$custo"))
                    .append("duracaoTotal",new BasicDBObject("$sum","$duracao"))
                    .append("dataHora",new BasicDBObject("$first","$dataHora"))
                )
            ),
            Aggregation.sort(Direction.ASC,"_id.dataHora")
    );
```

Since the custom class abstracts from the same basic class used by the built in helper methods, it can be used alongside them as shown.

How the basic process with the date math works here is that when you [`$subtract`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) one BSON Date object from another then the result is the milliseconds of difference, and in this case from the epoch date ( Date(0) ) which just extracts the milliseconds value. This allows you to do the math to round to the current date value by the modulo ( [`$mod`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) ) from the number of milliseconds in one day.

Much as you originally tried, when you then [`$add`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) that millisecond value to a BSON Date object the returned value is again a BSON Date. So adding to an object representing epoch returns a new Date Object, but rounded to the current date.

This is usually a lot more useful than extracting parts via [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/), and also works out to be a bit shorter to code, especially when adjusting the time from UTC as you are doing here.

Though the contruction of the `$group` here is a bit more terse than the helper functions of spring mongo are trying to avoid, it is a lot more efficient in the end than running a separate `$project` stage to transform the field values that you really only want in the `$group` stage anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and thanks for spending this time to explain the mongo limitation and workaround! I will try that approach

Comment: This answer rocks!