# How to project timestamp as an ISODate using Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

In the normal Mongo shell, it is possible to perform the following step during an aggregation to create an ISODate object from a Long timestamp, and therefore be able to use the various date helper functions (`$year`,`$month`, etc):

```
{
    $project:{
        'date': {
            $add: [
                new Date(0),
                    {
                    $multiply:[
                        '$seconds_timestamp_field',
                        1000
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
}}
```

Is something similar possible using Spring Data?  The `plus()` method does not appear to support a Java `Date` object as an argument.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use the Joda library to manipulate the data, preferably using the Joda lib > org.joda.time.DateTime.

Convert the DateTime object to an ISO using toDateTimeISO() method on the DateTime class.

Here is an example of the usage. but do use this once the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920945/spring-throws-cpnverternotfound-for-range-search-on-date-in-mongodb) asked is resolved.

```
Query query = new Query();
        DateTime dateTest = new DateTime(year, 1, 1, 0, 0);

        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("monthYear").gte(dateTest.toDateTimeISO()));
        System.out.println(query.toString());
        List<Spendings> spendingsList = dbConfig.getMongoOperations().find(query, Spendings.class, collectionName);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really cover what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to use the $year/$month/etc operators available in the aggregation framework, but these are only available for ISODate objects, whereas I just have timestamps stored in Mongo (as a number).  What I'm looking to do is convert the timestamp to an ISODate as one of the aggregation steps.

Comment: @JosephBlair If you have the timestamp in the epoch format then you can use the DateTime to convert it to the ISODate format

Comment: Late to this, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789189/aggregation-project-group-by-extracted-day-month-and-year-with-spring-data has an explanation and workaround for this.