# Spring throws ConverterNotFound for range search on date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm trying to do a range search on DateTime data format. The dates are being stored in Joda's DateTime format in the MongoDB.

When I do a FIND query for a data greater than a given date, the ConverterNotFoundException is being thrown.

Could someone please share information on why the conversation of Date object is being done to DateTime (Joda) &how can I possibly resolve this?

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.util.Date to type org.joda.time.DateTime
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:313) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:176) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1179) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1133) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:869) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:282) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:270) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:270) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:191) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2215) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1891) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1714) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1697) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:602) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

**Application Code**

```
Query query = new Query();
        DateTime dateTest = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0);
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("monthYear").gte(dateTest.toDateTimeISO()));
        System.out.println(query.toString());
        List<Model> spendingsList = dbConfig.getMongoOperations().find(query, Model.class, collectionName);
```

The **generated query** looks like below:

```
Query: { "monthYear" : { "$gte" : { $java : 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 } } }, Fields: null, Sort: null
```

**Annotation** used in the Model class

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private DateTime monthYear;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this behavior, found the following issues and solutions.

**Issue**

The data stored in the MongoDB is interpreted differently when the data type is read from different MongoDB UIs. Eg: Mongovue interprets the type as DateTime, DBeaver interprets it as Timestamp

**Solution**
Query the DB from the application with the date time object in Date format.

**Example**

```
int year;
DateTime monthYearFrom = new DateTime(year, 1, 1, 1, 0);
DateTime monthYearTo = new DateTime((year+1), 1, 1, 1, 0);
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("monthYear").gte(monthYearFrom.toDate()).lte(monthYearTo.toDate()));
```